# CSS Rule in media query not being recognized?

Tags: html, css

I have a media query which shoulda change the size of a div from 100% to a fixed 2000px. They are in different style sheets.

In the header contact.css is ABOVE styles.css
Here is an image of the console not seeing the rule, it doesn't even show it with a strike through: https://gyazo.com/dd140a95ed8a7d3454f5568a86f49bdc

(In this image, the browser size has been reduced to less than 700px)

contact.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

contact.css:

```
#PageC {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Media query in styles.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

#pageC {
    height: 2000px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors `#pageC` and `#PageC` are not the same.

Fix it and it will work for you as expected.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   #PageC {
      height: 2000px;
      margin-top: 120px;
   }
}
```

Comment: No idea how I didn't see that. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in contact.css you use completely different selector #PageC and in styles.css #pageC. It doesn't work because of *case-sensivity* of selectors.
Secondly, I suggest you to put all style for #pageC in one place, because it helps to optimize your work. 
For example, page.css can look so:

```
#pageC {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   #pageC {
    height: 2000px;
    margin-top: 120px;
   }
}
```